# Scrollbar hiding in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

In my webpage there's a dropdown with 4 links to about us, platform, contact us and information. While opening either of them a scrollbar (vertical) appears.

I have tried following codes for different web browser support:

```
.container {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  // IE 10+
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;  // Firefox
}
.container::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none;  // Safari and Chrome
}
```

works fine for chrome as well as safari. But for Firefox, it doesn't work. I know that `-moz-scrollbars-none` has been deprecated for latest firefox versions. Can someone help me in resolving the issue? I want that scrollbar shouldn't be visible but allow mouse wheel scroll.

Comment: try `overflow-y:hidden` in `.container`

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to do what you're trying to do in Firefox without the use of JavaScript.

Comment: I am new to JS, writing a JS for me would be difficult

Comment: try @Bhuwan example

Comment: Already tried, still not working as required in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to do without JavaScript in Firefox. If by any possible chance, try:

```
.container{
overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Firefox 64 it works well:

```
scrollbar-width: none;
```